Issues arise when more than three participants join the call
I'm currently trying to implement a call system using WebSocket on a Spring Boot server. When two participants connect via WebSocket, the call works well, including real-time transcription, but when three people call the Vonage phone number and connect via WebSocket, the delay becomes so severe that the call is almost unusable. However, if two people connect via the phone through WebSocket and one connects via HTML and JavaScript through WebSocket, the call works fine for all three participants. What could be the issue?
package dgdr.server.vonage;

import com.google.gson.JsonObject;
import com.google.gson.JsonParser;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.core.io.ByteArrayResource;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.http.client.MultipartBodyBuilder;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClient;
import org.springframework.web.socket.BinaryMessage;
import org.springframework.web.socket.CloseStatus;
import org.springframework.web.socket.TextMessage;
import org.springframework.web.socket.WebSocketSession;
import org.springframework.web.socket.handler.BinaryWebSocketHandler;
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;

import javax.sound.sampled.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URLDecoder;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.concurrent.*;

@Component
public class WebSocketHandler extends BinaryWebSocketHandler {

    private final ConcurrentMap<String, WebSocketSession> sessionMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
    private final ConcurrentMap<String, ByteArrayOutputStream> sessionAudioDataMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
    private final ConcurrentMap<String, File> sessionAudioFileMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
    private final ConversationRepository conversationRepository;

    @Autowired
    public WebSocketHandler(ConversationRepository conversationRepository) {
        this.conversationRepository = conversationRepository;
        ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(10);
        scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(this::saveAndSendAudioToFile, 3, 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }

    @Override
    public void handleBinaryMessage(WebSocketSession session, BinaryMessage message) {
        try {
            ByteBuffer buffer = message.getPayload();

            sessionAudioDataMap.computeIfAbsent(session.getId(), k -> new ByteArrayOutputStream());
            sessionAudioDataMap.get(session.getId()).write(buffer.array(), buffer.position(), buffer.remaining());

            for (WebSocketSession s : sessionMap.values()) {
                if (!s.isOpen() || s.getId().equals(session.getId())) {
                    continue;
                }

                synchronized (s) {
                    s.sendMessage(message);
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void afterConnectionEstablished(WebSocketSession session) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("참여자 : " + session.getId());
        String callerId = getCallerIdFromSession(session);
        createNewAudioFile(session.getId(), callerId);
        sessionMap.put(session.getId(), session);
    }

    @Override
    public void afterConnectionClosed(WebSocketSession session, CloseStatus status) throws Exception {
        sessionAudioDataMap.remove(session.getId());
        sessionAudioFileMap.remove(session.getId());
        sessionMap.remove(session.getId());
    }

    private void saveAndSendAudioToFile() {
        for (WebSocketSession session : sessionMap.values()) {
            if (!session.isOpen()) {
                continue;
            }

            byte[] audioData;
            audioData = sessionAudioDataMap.get(session.getId()).toByteArray();
            sessionAudioDataMap.get(session.getId()).reset();

            if (audioData.length > 0) {
                System.out.println("Saving audio data to file...");
                try {
                    appendToWavFile(audioData, sessionAudioFileMap.get(session.getId()));
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }
                processAudioFile(session);
            }
        }
    }

    private void processAudioFile(WebSocketSession session) {
        try {
            File audioFile = sessionAudioFileMap.get(session.getId());
            if (audioFile.exists() && audioFile.length() > 0) {
                byte[] audioData = Files.readAllBytes(audioFile.toPath());

                System.out.println("Clova STT API 호출 중...");
                createNewAudioFile(session.getId(), getCallerIdFromSession(session));

                sendToClovaSTT(audioData).subscribe(result -> {
                    if (result != null && !result.isEmpty()) {
                        saveConversation(session, result);
                        System.out.println("Transcription result: \n" + result);
                    }

                    String callerId = getCallerIdFromSession(session);
                    createNewAudioFile(session.getId(), callerId);
                }, error -> {
                    System.err.println("Error during transcription: " + error.getMessage());
                    error.printStackTrace();
                });
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void createNewAudioFile(String sessionId, String callerId) {
        File audioDir = new File("audio");
        if (!audioDir.exists()) {
            audioDir.mkdirs();
        }
        String timeStamp = LocalDateTime.now().format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss"));
        File audioFile = new File(audioDir, "audio_" + callerId + "_" + timeStamp + ".wav");
        sessionAudioFileMap.put(sessionId, audioFile);
    }

    private void appendToWavFile(byte[] audioData, File file) throws IOException {
        boolean append = file.exists();
        int bufferSize = 16384;
        try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file, append);
             AudioInputStream audioInputStream = new AudioInputStream(
                     new ByteArrayInputStream(audioData), getAudioFormat(), audioData.length)) {

            if (append) {
                fos.getChannel().position(file.length());
            } else {
                AudioSystem.write(audioInputStream, AudioFileFormat.Type.WAVE, fos);
                return;
            }

            byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
            int bytesRead;
            while ((bytesRead = audioInputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                fos.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            }
        }
    }

    private AudioFormat getAudioFormat() {
        return new AudioFormat(8000, 16, 1, true, false);
    }

    private Mono<String> sendToClovaSTT(byte[] wavData) {
        WebClient clovaClient = WebClient.builder()
                .baseUrl(Constants.CLOVA_SPEECH_INVOKE_URL)
                .defaultHeader("X-CLOVASPEECH-API-KEY", Constants.CLOVA_SPEECH_SECRET_KEY)
                .build();

        MultipartBodyBuilder builder = new MultipartBodyBuilder();
        builder.part("media", new ByteArrayResource(wavData))
                .header("Content-Disposition", "form-data; name=media; filename=audio.wav")
                .contentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA);

        String paramsJson = """
                {
                    "language": "ko-KR",
                    "completion": "sync",
                    "noiseFiltering": true,
                    "fullText": true,
                    "diarization": {
                        "enable": false
                    }
                }
                """;
        builder.part("params", paramsJson)
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);

        return clovaClient.post()
                .uri("/recognizer/upload")
                .bodyValue(builder.build())
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToMono(String.class)
                .map(response -> {
                    System.out.println("Full Response: " + response);
                    JsonObject jsonObject = JsonParser.parseString(response).getAsJsonObject();
                    return jsonObject.get("text").getAsString();
                })
                .doOnError(e -> {
                    System.err.println("STT API error: " + e.getMessage());
                    e.printStackTrace();
                });
    }

    private String getCallerIdFromSession(WebSocketSession session) {
        String callerId = "unknown";

        URI uri = session.getUri();
        String query = uri.getQuery();
        if (query != null) {
            for (String param : query.split("&")) {
                String[] keyValue = param.split("=");
                if (keyValue.length == 2 && keyValue[0].equals("caller-id")) {
                    callerId = URLDecoder.decode(keyValue[1], StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        return callerId;
    }

    private void saveConversation(WebSocketSession session, String transcription) {
        Conversation conversation = new Conversation();
        conversation.setStartTime(LocalDateTime.now());
        conversation.setCallerId(getCallerIdFromSession(session));
        conversation.setTranscription(transcription);
        conversationRepository.save(conversation);
    }
}


package dgdr.server.vonage;

import com.vonage.client.VonageClient;
import com.vonage.client.voice.ncco.ConnectAction;
import com.vonage.client.voice.ncco.EventType;
import com.vonage.client.voice.ncco.Ncco;
import com.vonage.client.voice.ncco.WebSocketEndpoint;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class VonageService {
    private final VonageClient vonageClient;

    public VonageService(@Value("${vonage.apiKey}") String apiKey,
                         @Value("${vonage.applicationId}") String applicationId,
                         @Value("${vonage.privateKeyPath}") String privateKeyPath,
                         @Value("${vonage.apiSecret}") String apiSecret) {
        this.vonageClient = VonageClient.builder()
                .applicationId(applicationId)
                .apiKey(apiKey)
                .apiSecret(apiSecret)
                .privateKeyPath(privateKeyPath)
                .build();
    }

    public Ncco createConversationNcco(String callerId) {
        String websocketUri = String.format("wss://" + Constants.URL + "/ws/audio?caller-id=%s", callerId);

        WebSocketEndpoint websocketEndpoint = WebSocketEndpoint
                .builder(websocketUri, "audio/l16;rate=8000")
                .build();

        ConnectAction connectAction = ConnectAction.builder()
                .endpoint(websocketEndpoint)
                .eventType(EventType.SYNCHRONOUS)
                .build();

        return new Ncco(connectAction);
    }
}

